# Submitting table row data to another table using an input field in php

Tags: php, mysql, submit

How can I submit a table row data to another table using an input field in PHP and MYSQL?

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
  <input type="number" name="code" placeholder="Code..."/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Post.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $code = $_POST['code'];


    $getCode = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE code=$code";
    mysqli_query($connection, $getCode);
    if ($_POST['code'] == $code) {
      $migrating = "INSERT INTO managment(price) VALUES ($price) SELECT 
      price FROM products";
      mysqli_query($connection, $migrating);
      header("location: index.php");
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) is :

```
INSERT INTO managment(price) SELECT price FROM products
```

Maybe you want add a `WHERE` clause :

```
INSERT INTO managment(price) SELECT price FROM products WHERE code=$code
```

Note: in your code, `$_POST['code'] == $code` doesn't make sense, because of `$code = $_POST['code']` earlier.

I also suggest you to have a look to [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to secure your queries.

---

Your code updated (untested) :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $code = $_POST['code'];

    $getCode = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE code=$code";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $getCode);
    if (!$result) die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['code'] == $code) {
        $migrating = "INSERT INTO managment(price) 
                      SELECT price FROM products WHERE code=$code";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $migrating);
        if (!$result2) die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, could you provide me the PHP code that completes my requirement...I am a beginner in PHP